# Retrieving Stock Quotes using Eclipse - Error: The value of the local variable is not used

Tags: java, stock

I'm trying out a java application to retrieve stock quotes using Yahoo API. 
http://greatwebguy.com/programming/java/stock-quote-and-chart-from-yahoo-in-java/

No amendments to the sample code above. I've just added a main class.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        StockBean stock = StockTickerDAO.getInstance().getStockPrice("GOOG");     
    }
}
```

I'm unable to execute the main class due to:
*The value of the local variable stock is not used.*

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything *wrong*. You're just not using the retrieved stock figures.

Take a peak inside the `StockBean` class to see what methods it exposes. I am assuming something like `StockBean.getPrice()` will be publicly exposed. Just use that as so:

```
StockBean stock = StockTickerDAO.getInstance().getStockPrice("GOOG");
System.out.println("Stock Price: " + stock.getPrice());
```

For debugging / logging purposes, you might want a convenient approach that spits out the contents of the entire bean. That can be done if your `StockBean` had the `toString` method overridden.

If that was the case, you could've just done the below and it would've neatly enlisted all the properties.

```
System.out.println(stock);
```

If you can edit the `StockBean` class, I suggest you implement `toString` by using Eclipse or by hand.

Answer (score 0):

It's just what the message said: you don't do anything with the variable `stock`. Normally this is a warning but it might have beed changed to be an error. To fix it, use the variable or just don't introduce it.

Alternatively, adapt the Eclipse settings to make this a warning or even ignore it, or add the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` annotation to the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo discontinued it's stock quote service after it was acquired by Verizon. Intrinio is the alternative right now. There is a sample java program in GitHub at https://github.com/pmkent/intrinio-java-sample